# Find percent value of a color between two known colors

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, hex

What is the best way to determine the percent value of a color between two given values. In other words, what is the best way to calculate the % position of color C?

Color A - 0x0000FF
Color B - 0x00CCFF
Color C - 0x00FFFF

Thanks!

Comment: there's also this: https://code.google.com/p/mojocolors/ might be worth looking into

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well it's not that straight forward, because it depends on how you decide to quantize color.

You could do it through HSB, which is the more correct way in my opinion (though not necessarily a fact though) or just use the hex value.

quickest is probably to do it using the hax values

```
var colour:uint = 0x9900CC;
var r:uint = colour >> 16;
var g:uint = colour >> 8 & 0xFF;
var b:uint = colour & 0xFF;
```

.this will give you the value of each channel(c) (ABC being the colours)

then do the math for each channel (c)

```
(cB - cA)/(cC - cA)
```

then once you get each of these chanels, you can add them together and divide by 3.

there is one problem though, if Colour A and C are ever the same for any channel, you need to add an exception (because cC and CA are zero and you can't divide by zero), at that point you also need to decide how to handle that difference.

Comment: I would definitely also try it using HSL, HSL, or one of the other cylindrical color systems.  Depending on your application, you may get better (or more meaningful) results.

Comment: Still I wonder what the most appropriate way of dealing with a case where two numbers are the same and  and the number in-between is different, mathematically the difference is infinity. This would be the same even whn dealing with HSV(HSB,HSL)